# Netlogo: Ask expected this input to be a command block, but got a number instead

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I'm getting this error "Ask expected this input to be a command block, but got a number instead" inside my setup procedure...

```
to setup
....
....
....
....
[ask color gray + 1.5]
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`ask` takes an agent or agentset as its first argument and a command block (something like `[ ... ]` that has commands in it) as its second. So, in your case, you probably want something like:

`ask turtles [ set color gray + 1.5 ]`